# Encog Workbench Analysis Wizard Multiple Target Field

Tags: neural-network, encog

I am using Encog Workbench Analysis Wizard. 
As I understood "target field" is the output neuron. Nevertheless, in my network I have 75 input neurons and 44 output neurons. I cannot figure out how I set up more than one target field in the Analysis Wizard. Could anyone help with it, please? Or do I misunderstand the conception of the target field in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Run the analyst wizard as normal. Let it choose one field for a single output. Then go into the `.ega` file. Scroll down to where it says `[NORMALIZE:RANGE]`. You will see a list of inputs and one output at the end. Now change the word `input` to `output` for all the relevant neurons.

Then you can change `equilateral` to `oneof` for all the target fields if you are using a 1 of n classification.

Yes `target` and `output` mean the same thing in this case.

If you are starting out with this, I highly recommend you begin the problem with say 5 or 10 input and output neurons, to greatly simplify your problem.